# Change dynamically "from" in iPOJO metadata

Tags: java, ipojo

I have a problem relating to iPOJO, as example:

1. I define and deploy a component A which provide a “HelloService” service (interface). And an instance of component A named  “instance_A”
2. I define also a component B requiring “HelloService” service in A. the implementation of B declared a dependency:

   > HelloService hello;

And in metadata.xml, I declare:

```
<ipojo>
     <component classname="B_class" name="B" immediate="true">
     <requires field=" hello" from="instance_A">
     </requires>
     </component>
     <instance component="B" name="call"/>
</ipojo>
```

3. Now, I want implement a component C to dynamically control change (from="instance_A") in metadata to another (ex. from="instance_D")

How I can do it (component C) to change this "from"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on [update dynamically targeting provider in iPOJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776583/update-dynamically-targeting-provider-in-ipojo/26797867#26797867) to dynamically change dependency filter.

However in your case it seems that interceptors would give you more control:
http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo/apache-felix-ipojo-userguide/ipojo-advanced-topics/service-binding-interceptors.html

1. Create a ranking interceptor handling your dependency
2. When a new provider arrives, sort the set of providers in the order you want. This adapts the service binding.